# CSS Drop Down Div animations?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have been trying to get my drop down cart to fade/slide up when you hover over the cart icon. (Like the submenus)

However, I am not a CSS transition wizard! Have tried generic fades using transition element but it did not work.

My Drop down works by just displaying a second div when you hover over it - which has the php functions to grab the users cart items & price.

I am beginning to think whether there is a much better way to do this?

Website with drop down cart in header: [My Website with Cart](http://www.forumjewellers.ds-demo.co.uk/)

My Code: https://jsfiddle.net/em2bvxvx/

Cart Drop Down CSS:

```css
    .mini-cart {background-color:red;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: 22px 22px;width: 22px;height: 22px;font-size: 10px;padding-top: 6px;padding-left: 7.4px;margin-top: 13px;margin-left: 14px;color: #000;}

    .shopping-cart {position: relative;display: inline-block;}

    .minicart-dropdown {width: 300px;display: none;background-color: #fff;min-width: 160px;box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);z-index: 1;right: 0px;padding: 20px;top: 40px;}

    .minicart-dropdown .size-woocommerce_thumbnail {height: auto;max-width: 50px;}

    .minicart-dropdown a {color: #fff;padding: 12px 16px;text-decoration: none;display: block;}

    .minicart-dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

    .shopping-cart:hover .minicart-dropdown {display: block;}

    .minicart-dropdown > .cart-buttons {display: flex;color: #fff;margin-top: 20px;}

    .minicart-dropdown > .cart-buttons > .minicart-vb, .minicart-co {width:49%; text-align:center;background-color: #01273a!important;cursor:pointer;}

    .minicart-dropdown > .cart-buttons > .minicart-co {margin-left: 15px;}

    .minicart-dropdown .content {margin-top: 20px;}
```

Comment: To make a working example, please also share your HTML.

Comment: Transitions are pretty straight forward. `display: none;` can't transition to `display: block;` with animation. You can however use `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transition: all 0.3s;` to hide and `visibility: visible; opacity: 1;  transition: all 0.3s;` to show. This will animate in if you use it on hover or adding a `.show` class or however you want it to work.  Don't have a lot of time now so couldnt make an example. You DO need a transition on both otherwise when hiding it won't animate.

Comment: @Gezzasa Ah right ok - I understand that. Thank you for that. I will fiddle around and see what i can come up with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple as that in CSS. You need to create a keyframe animation for the effect `fade` with the help `visibility`, `opacity` and `transform` properties. With the help of `opacity` you can set your initial state of your div to be hidden and `transform` can help you push your elements either `X` or `Y` axis.

```css
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  to { 
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.dropdown {
   animation: fade 2s linear forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use transform property, opacity, and visibility, instead of hiding your box, this is actually the properties used by the site that you mentioned

Like this example.https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/ypqvtnem/

```css
.minicart-dropdown {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    top: 40px;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
    
.shopping-cart:hover .minicart-dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0%);
    visibility: visible;
}
```